# не работает скрипт для голосования в опросах вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я написал скрипт, который должен чекать определенный чат на наличие новых опросов и голосовать за нужный мне вариант ответа, но он почему-то не работает и я не знаю почему. Можете помочь с данным скриптом? Объясните, почему он не работает, и подскажите, что нужно исправить, чтобы он работал.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

access_token = 'token'
chat_id = 2000000000
desired_answer = 'вариант ответа за который нужно голосовать'

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=access_token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

user_info = vk.users.get()
user_name = f"{user_info[0]['last_name']} {user_info[0]['first_name']}"

print(f"Бот запущен от имени пользователя: {user_name}")
print("Ожидание новых опросов...")

def process_poll_event(event):
    if 'attachments' in event.message and 'poll' in event.message['attachments']:
        attachments = event.message['attachments']
        for attachment in attachments:
            if attachment['type'] == 'poll':
            poll_id = attachment['poll']['id']
            poll = vk.polls.getById(owner_id=event.peer_id, is_board=False, poll_id=poll_id)
            options = poll['answers']
            for option in options:
                if option['text'] == desired_answer:
                    if option['id'] is not None:
                        vk.polls.addVote(owner_id=event.peer_id, poll_id=poll_id, answer_ids=[option['id']])
                        print("Проголосовал!")
                    break

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.peer_id is not None and event.peer_id == chat_id:
            process_poll_event(event)
```